# Shuffling the digits of an integer so that the ratio between the resulting numbers is fixed.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Suppose we have a 3-digit integer with all digits distinct. If we create its two shift numbers (resulting by rotation of the original digits), the ratio between the two subsequent numbers (if we order them in ascending or descending order) must be fixed.
Find this number.

> Suppose the number is xyz and the two resulting numbers, if we shift the digits to the right, are yzx and zxy. Assuming $xyz<yzx<zxy$ (there is no equal, since all digits are distinct), we want $\frac{zxy}{yzx} = \frac{yzx}{xyz} = k$, where k: rational.

Furthermore, it is easy to deduce that 0 is excluded, or one of the resulting numbers would be 2-digit.

I have found 2 such sets of numbers, {243, 324, 432} and {486, 648, 864} and now I am trying to formulate an algebraic solution.

If xyz is the original number, the first rotation is yzx and can be found as follows:

$yzx = xyz*10+x-1000*x$.

Also $zxy= yzx*10+y-1000*y$.

Assuming wlg that $xyz<yzx<zxy$, we must have $\frac{xyz*10+x-1000*x}{xyz} = \frac{yzx*10+y-1000*y}{xyz*10+x-1000*x} = k$

I also noticed that if the 3 numbers are in ascending order $xyz<yzx<zxy$, then their differences
$yzx-xyz$ and $zxy-yzx$ have the same 3 digits in rotation.

but I don't think I can advance it any further...

Comment: Numerically these are the only solutions.

Comment: In other bases, from 3 to 100, thirty-three bases have no solution, twenty-nine bases have two solutions each, and the base 79 has twenty-five solutions.

Comment: If you fix the base and the number of digits you can just let a computer search for the solutions. Maybe it's more interesting if we don't fix at least one of the two. For example, if we just fix the base, can we find $n$-digits numbers with this property for each $n$? Or for infinitely many $n$?

Comment: You cannot assume $xyz < yzx < zxy$ This would violate your own solutions. If $xyz = 243,$ then $yzx$ is not $324,$ but $432.$

Comment: By the way $\frac{b^2z+bx+y}{b^2y+bz+x}=\frac{b^2y+bz+x}{b^2x+by+z}$ can be simplified to $b(y^2-xz)=(x^2-yz)$.

Comment: According to the sets number you gave, you must get  $k=4/3$ and to reach this result write I would have write 

$$ (yzx)^2=(xyz)(zxy) $$ and write it in a form of multivariable polynom in $x,y,z$

Comment: In base 17, the number 1249 can be doubled three times by rotation.  Similar for 1248(17) in base 33

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We want to find triples of integers $(x,y,z)$ such that
$$0\lt x\le 9, 0\le y\le 9,0\le z\le 9\tag1$$
$$x\not=y,y\not=z,z\not=x\tag2$$
$$\frac{100z+10x+y}{100y+10z+x}=\frac{100y+10z+x}{100x+10y+z}\tag3$$

From $(3)$, we get

$$ yz-x^2=10(xz-y^2)\implies yz\equiv x^2\pmod{10}\tag4$$
and
$$x=-5z+\sqrt{25z^2+10y^2+yz}\implies \sqrt{25z^2+10y^2+yz}\ \in\mathbb Z\tag5$$

Also, if $y\lt z\lt x$, then $yz-x^2=10(xz-y^2)$ does not hold since LHS is negative while RHS is positve.

If $x\lt z\lt y$, then $yz-x^2=10(xz-y^2)$ does not hold since LHS is positive while RHS is negative.

- If $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{10}$, then $yz=21$ and so $(y,z)=(3,7),(7,3)$ each of which doesn't satisfy $(5)$.
- If $x^2\equiv 4\pmod{10}$, then $yz=4,14,24,54$ and so $(y,z)=(1,4),(4,1),(7,2),(3,8),(4,6),(6,4),(6,9),(9,6)$ where only $(y,z)=(6,4),(9,6)$ satisfy $(5)$ with $x=8,12$ respectively. (we don't need to consider the case $(y,z)=(2,7)$ since then $x=8$ for which $y\lt z\lt x$ holds. Also, we don't need to consider the case $(y,z)=(8,3)$ since then $x=2$ for which $x\lt z\lt y$ holds.)
- If $x^2\equiv 9\pmod{10}$, then $yz=9$ and so $(y,z)=(1,9),(9,1)$ each of which doesn't satisfy $(5)$.
- If $x^2\equiv 6\pmod{10}$, then $yz=6,16,36,56$ and so $(y,z)=(1,6),(6,1),(3,2),(2,8),(8,2),(4,9),(9,4),(7,8)$ where only $(y,z)=(3,2)$ satisfies $(5)$ with $x=4$. (we don't need to consider the case $(y,z)=(2,3)$ since then $x=4$ or $6$ for which $y\lt z\lt x$ holds. Also, we don't need to consider the case $(y,z)=(8,7)$ since then $x=4$ or $6$ for which $x\lt z\lt y$ holds.)
- If $x^2\equiv 5\pmod{10}$, then $x=5$ and one of $y,z$ is $5$, which does not satisfy $(2)$.

So, the only solutions are
$$\color{red}{(x,y,z)=(4,3,2),(8,6,4)}$$
where we have
$$\frac{243}{324}=\frac{324}{432}=\frac 34=\frac{486}{648}=\frac{648}{864}$$

Comment: Splendid answer!

Comment: mathlove you are a genius!

Answer (score 3):

**Not a complete answer but can be open for further discussion**

See one famous example for [cyclic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number):

$$\frac{1}{7}=0.\overline{142857}$$

we have

$$142857:285714:428571:571428:714285,857142=1:2:3:4:5:6$$

> You may pick up $1:2:4$ for a case of $6$ digits.

In general for base $b$, the cyclic-permutation decimal can be in the form of

$$\frac{b^{p-1}-1}{p}$$

Besides the cyclic numbers mentioned in the above link, a number of **subsets** of $\dfrac{k}{37}$ give **further kinds** of cyclic numbers (including $0$):

- $k\in \{ 1,10,26 \}$ gives $0.\overline{027},0.\overline{270},0.\overline{702}$
- $k\in \{ 2,15,20 \}$ gives $0.\overline{054},0.\overline{405},0.\overline{540}$
- $k\in \{ 3,4,30 \}$ gives $0.\overline{081},0.\overline{108},0.\overline{810}$
- $k\in \{ 5,13,19 \}$ gives $0.\overline{135},0.\overline{351},0.\overline{513}$
- $k\in \{ 6,8,23 \}$ gives $0.\overline{162},0.\overline{216},0.\overline{621}$
- $k\in \{ 7,33,34 \}$ gives $0.\overline{162},0.\overline{216},0.\overline{621}$
- $k\in \{ 9,12,16 \}$ gives $0.\overline{243},0.\overline{324},0.\overline{432}$
- $k\in \{ 11,27,36 \}$ gives $0.\overline{297},0.\overline{729},0.\overline{972}$
- $k\in \{ 14,29,31 \}$ gives $0.\overline{378},0.\overline{783},0.\overline{837}$
- $k\in \{ 17,22,35 \}$ gives $0.\overline{459},0.\overline{594},0.\overline{945}$
- $k\in \{ 18,24,32 \}$ gives $0.\overline{486},0.\overline{648},0.\overline{864}$
- $k\in \{ 21,25,28 \}$ gives $0.\overline{567},0.\overline{675},0.\overline{756}$

> Only subsets $\{ 9,12,16 \}$ and $\{ 18,24,32 \} $ are your favourable cases.

Note that $27\times 37=999$

- For $k=3n$, $$\frac{k}{27} = 0.\overline{n}$$
- For other $k$ values, there're $6$ triplets of cyclic numbers but there're no favourable cases here.

Comment: Probably would be helpful to note how to find $37$ (factorize $999$).

Comment: @aschepler Thanks to your response.  In fact, the number $37$ is not belong to the category in the linked.  Subsets of fractions for $\dfrac{k}{37}$ give cyclic permuations.  We need further investigation.

Comment: Right, that category is for finding numbers $n$ where all the $k/n$ are cycles of each other. But we know $m/n$ in base $b$ has $d$ repeating digits if $\gcd(n,b)=1$ and $d$ is the smallest number where $n \mid b^d-1$. Since $999=3^3 \cdot 37$, some potential denominators are $27$ or $37$. $27$ gives more triples like 185:518:851 :: 5:14:23, but I guess none are in geometric progression. Also, your triplets for $k$ are $\{k, 10k, 100k\} \pmod{37}$; in general the numerators are $kb^q \pmod{n}$, but it's not clear when taking the representatives in $1\ldots n$ is geometric.