# An interesting feature of $857142$

Tags: puzzle

In 2002, a math competition of India named Pradanya meant to ask two 6-digit numbers $P=abcdef$ and $Q=defabc$ such that $P=6 Q$. We can write $P=1000X+Y, Q=1000Y+X$, where $X=abc$ and $Y=def$ are 3-digit numbers. Then we get $$\frac{X}{Y}=\frac{6000-1}{1000-6}=\frac{857}{142}.$$ Hence $P=857142.$

This interesting number gives rise to the following question:

Find $2n$-digit numbers $P_{2n}$ and $Q_{2n}$ are such that  $P_{2n} = m Q_{2n}$, $m \in \{2,3,...,9\}$, where $P_{2n} = \{X_n\} \{Y_n\}, ~ Q_{2n}=\{Y_n\} \{X_n\}; \{X_n\} = x_1x_2x_3...x_n,~ \{Y_n\}=y_1y_2y_3...y_n$ are $n$-digit numbers.
We will get the equation $$\frac{(m 10^n-1)}{{10^n-m}}=\frac{\{X_n\}}{\{Y_n\}}$$
to solve, Numerics suggest no solution for $n=1,2,4,5$ and one solution $m=6$ for $n=3$ which has already produced $P_6=857142.$ The question is:
Are there other such numbers as $P_6$  and what could be possible mathematical connections?

Comment: This is related to [cyclic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number). For example, $\frac{94117647\,05882352}{05882352\,94117647} = 16$.

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3717744/42969.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3835383/a-problem-on-basic-algebra)