# A problem on basic algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

A six-digit integer is formed by placing two 3-digit integers side by-side. If the larger of the two integers is placed ahead of the smaller integer, the number formed is six times greater than if the smaller integer is placed ahead of the larger one. What is the sum of the two 3-digit integers?

Can anyone give me any hint how to solve it.

I have assumed the bigger integer to be $b$ and the smaller to be $s$

Then the two numbers formed are $1000s + b$ and $1000b + s$

Accordingly $(1000b + s) - (1000s + b) = 6(1000s + b)$

After this I am unable to think any clue.

Comment: garaiYou may see this question:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720480/an-interesting-feature-of-857142?noredirect=1#comment7910640_3720480

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be $1000b+s=6(1000s+b)$.

That is, $994b=5999s$.

That is, $7\times142b=7\times857s$, or $142b=857s$.

Note that $142$ and $857$ are relatively prime.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: note that $\dfrac17=0.\overline{142857}$ and $\dfrac67=0.\overline{857142}$

Comment: how does that help, can you explain a little bit ?

Comment: if $142b$ is a multiple of $857$ and $b$ has only three digits, then $b$ must be $857$; can you take it from there?

Comment: and similarly s must be 142 !

Comment: $s$ must be $142b/857=142$